# How to get access_token from client side for signed in user? using Azure AD B2C hybrid flow

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have a web app on asp.net core 7 that is protected by Azure AD B2C authentication. This part is working and the user is authenticated properly server side, and I can get an access_token server side thanks to AuthorizeForScopes attribute and ITokenAcquisition with GetAuthenticationResultForUserAsync.

Now I need to get an user_access token client side so I can call a web api directly from javascript without the need to re-signing the user.

the client side code is :

```html
<script src="https://alcdn.msauth.net/browser/2.5.1/js/msal-browser.js"></script>

<script type="module">

    const msalInstance = new msal.PublicClientApplication({
        auth: {
            clientId: "bbd0f8e1-a81a-43c6-82d8-xxxxxx",
            authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/cfc1d2e8-3626-4dca-9cd7-xxxxxx",
        },
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: "localStorage",
            storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
        }
    });

    const silentRequest = {
        scopes: ["https://xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/webapi/access_as_user"],
        loginHint: "me@email.com"
    };

    const loginResponse = await msalInstance.ssoSilent(silentRequest);


</script>
```

On Azure AD B2C the config is
Manage > Authentication > Implicit grant and hybrid flows > ID tokens (used for implicit and hybrid flows) checked.

Also I think the ssoSilent method is not recommended any more.

When I run the code I have the error Unsafe attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin xxx to the /authorize endpoint like if it's trying to re-authenticate the user instead of picking it from the cookie.

How can I get the `access_token` client side from the user logged in server side?

Answer (score 0):

By default, access tokens are not share between applications. You may share the token with your api trough a authenticated (An id token will be required) and secure (trough HTTPS). A better option from a security perspective is to share a [refresh token which can be revoked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-revokesigninsessions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) with less setup than access tokens.

Regarding the iframe error, the /authorize endpoint will always be reached as part of any silent. Try [Interactive requests with prompt=none](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-prompt-behavior#interactive-requests-with-promptnone) as a way to avoid such error.